# Human Capital Vs TFP

Tags: economic-growth, productivity, solow, endogenous-growth, human-capital

I'm interested in familiarizing myself with some of the intra-debates that have occurred over the years, having to do with Mankiw, Romer, Weil (1992) and Klenow, Rodriguez-Clare (1997). Some argue that TFP growth can sufficiently account for cross-country variations in output per capita. Others argue that we need a model of Human Capital.

I am just interested in reading about, and catching up with the literature on this.

Are there any papers or books that you guys can recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Romer (1986): Increasing Returns to Long Run Growth
- Lucas (1988): On the Mechanics of Economic Development
- Romer (1990): Endogenous Technological Change
- Jones (1995):  Time Series Tests of Endogenous Growth Models

These are all classic papers in this vein of endogenous growth and questions of cross-country convergence/divergence.

Comment: +1 but please consider providing hyperlinks to those papers, it would improve the answer and avoid ambiguity in cases where authors published more than 1 publication in given year

Comment: Good point, these authors are prolific. I added the paper titles to avoid confusion.